# If column A contains a certain string, sum the number of cells with the string in column D

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets: *Totals*, and *Features*.

I want one cell on the *Totals* sheet to equal the number of observations within column `D` of the *Features* sheet, when the values in column `D` contain a certain piece of string within it.

I saw something like this:  `=SUMIF(A:A, "POS", D:D)` but do not know how to get it to give me when more than that string exists in the column.

For example; the row is not only:

```
POS
```

It is:

```
This row is POS type text
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  I made an answer based on the function you're trying to implement, but after re-reading your Q, I'm not sure that is really what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the wildcard `*` character in your `SumIf` function, to search for values that contain `"POS"`, like so:

```
=SUMIF('Features'!A:A,"*POS*",'Features'!D:D)
```

Comment: @pnuts from what I can tell, OP wants a SUMIFs using a substring as the criteria.

Comment: @pnuts but now that I re-read the Q, I'm not sure that a VLOOKUP might be more appropriate. Requested clarification :)

Comment: This worked!  I'm not sure why this gave me so much trouble!  Thank you!